# Output image with build

Tags: c#, image, embedded-resource, migradoc

I am using MigraDoc, and would like to insert an image in a document. The simplest way to do this, is to provide a path for the image file (rather than having it in the resources). So what I would like to do is, to include an image as a file, alongside the other files in the build. Then MigraDoc can use the image based on relative path.

But I have no clue how to do this or if it is even possible. So can I make my project include an image file, **outside** the resources.

**P.S.** I know that there is a work around, where you include the image in the resources, save it in a temporary folder before MigraDoc has to use it. It just seems like a simpler design, if the image is always available.

**P.P.S.** There is a work around, to make MigraDoc use images from the project resources (see accepted answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown on the MigraDoc site you can use images you have as a `byte[]` to create PDF files. This can easily be used with images from resources (as shown on the site).

You just convert the image resource to a special string and pass that string where MigraDoc expects a filename.

```
static string MigraDocFilenameFromByteArray(byte[] image)
{
    return "base64:" +
           Convert.ToBase64String(image);
}
```

Link to official MigraDoc site:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDoc_FilelessImages.ashx

And MigraDoc can also use images that are stored in the program folder with your assemblies. You can use the `Assembly` class to find out where your assembly is stored and search that folder for images that should be there. This has nothing to do with MigraDoc, just some basic .NET features.

Comment: Thank you. It is correct that my question is not directly related to MigraDoc. I just added the tag, since it was a part of the root cause of my problem.

Comment: The MigraDoc tag is appropriate, but "does not support" could be misleading. There is one solution using the "base64:" prefix and resources, and another solution that is not related to MigraDoc, but still could be relevant for other MigraDoc users.

Comment: That is a good point. I have changed the wordings in my question. Thank you.